# Pull password from gnome keyring in Julia?

Tags: julia, gnome, password-encryption

I’ve looked around but can not find a julia package that will let me pull an encrypted password which is stored in my linux gnome keyring. I use it for keeping scripts that connect to SQL servers, anonymous because I have to distribute them to several group members.

In R, the “keyringer” package has a “decrypt_gk_pw” function that can pull a stored password right from the gnome keyring. Is there anything analogous in Julia or would we have to build it?

Comment: that function just calles `secret-tool`, you can call that yourself in julia

Comment: Would you care to point me to an example?  Thx. J

Answer (score 0):

https://rdrr.io/cran/keyringr/src/R/decrypt_gk_pw.R

```
invisible(system(paste("secret-tool lookup ", key_value_pairs, sep=""), intern=TRUE))
```

so:

```
> secret-tool store --label=mylabel db mydb user user1
Password: 
> julia -e 'read(`secret-tool lookup db mydb user user1`, String) |> println'
blah
```

if you need it to go to your clipboard, you can replace the `println` with `clipboard`

Comment: Thx. Close but first of all clipboard doesn't work, with Julia.  When I try to use it in and ODBC call it returns the value with double quotes around it so doesn't work.  Here is how I'm trying to use it ``` conn2 = ODBC.Connection("Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=66.66.66.66;DATABASE=dbname;UID=username;PWD='read(`secret-tool lookup val1 word val2 words`, String)'") ```

Comment: figuring out how to remove quotes can't be that hard right?

Comment: Don't be insulting now! :-)  Its not that simple! https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/

Comment: ```read(` cmd `, String)``` gives you a string, what you do with that string is up to you and has nothing to do with this question, you should ask on discourse for entry-level usage question like how to manipulate a string in Julia

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution, and it does work to hide the password, but anyone who knows Julia can simply remove the semicolon at the end, and it will appear, so not exactly what I wanted. I have to circulate this code to colleagues and others. The syntax for the ODBC connection is very specific with respect to “,” and “;” . Thx. J

```
con3 = ODBC.Connection(
    "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;
    SERVER=66.66.66.66;
    DATABASE=dbname;
    UID=username;
    PWD=$(read(`secret-tool lookup word1 word2 word3 word4`,String))");
```

Comment: Some more context would help here. If others are able to run this code, can't they also just run the `secret-tool` themselves and get the password that way? Or if you were using R, they could run the `decrypt_gk_pw` function themselves and make the password appear? I'm unclear on what your setup is and what threat model we're looking at.

Comment: By the way, the ODBC connection syntax is [as specified by Microsoft's SQL Server driver](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server/). It requires semi-colons because comma is used to separate the server IP from the port number (if specified).

Comment: @SundarR Thanks, yes correct about the problems/challenges with MS's ODBC driver.  As for context, I need to run this code, and show the code and results (think knitted to pdf in RStudio) to clients/colleagues, but I don't want to show them my login credentials.  And yes, if they access to my computer, which they won't, then they could use secret-tool to find the credentials.